# weird behavior with border

Tags: html, css

I've written a code to place two images side by side and show some text on hover, but I came across a weird behavior I can't explain and I was wondering if anyone can explain it to me.
Everything works fine with the code, but as soon as I add borders to the `.project-tile` class, to add borders around the image, both images collapse to the center.
I have tried to isolate the problem but I can't really figure it out, anyone has any idea?
codepen: https://codepen.io/pafestivo/pen/JjvNMmJ?editors=1100

Comment: Border adds to the  width and your wrapper div, width `900px`, is already at max with `400px` * 2 + `100px` gap. Increasing wrappers's width, or decreasing any the child width or gap by border size *2 will fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the css [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property. By default, the value of box-sizing is `content-box`, which means the border is not constrained by the `width: 400px;` and instead causes the divs to overflow their width and trigger wrapping.

Setting `box-sizing: border-box;` on `.project-tile` will allow you to add borders while keeping the current positioning.